# Partial Function pattern match split into a class and a trait

Tags: scala, partialfunction

Lift uses a PartialFunction on their implementation of Comet Actors, and you usually end up with this on your class:

```
override def lowPriority: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = {
  case MyCaseClass1(a)        => do something here
  case MyCaseClass2(a)        => do something here
  case AlwaysPresentCaseClass => default action
}
```

What I'd like to do, and I'm not sure if it is even possible is to split that Partial Function so that the last case can be moved into a trait.

So when I have a new comet actor I simply do:

```
class MyNewComet extends MyActorTrait {
  override def lowPriority: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = {
    case MyCaseClass1(a)        => do something here
    case MyCaseClass2(a)        => do something here
  }
}
```

And Somehow the trait MyActorTrait will have the missing

```
case AlwaysPresentCaseClass => default action
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
trait MyActorTrait extends /* whatever class provides lowPriority */ {
   def default: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
           case AlwaysPresentCaseClass => default action
   }

   abstract override def lowPriority: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] =
       super.lowPriority orElse default
}
```

The only problem is that you can't do `MyNewComet extends MyActorTrait`. Instead, you can either have `class MyNewCometDefault extends MyNewComet with MyActorTrait`, or `new MyNewComet with MyActorTrait`.

Comment: Thanks both for you answers. I picked this one because @daniel went the extra mile and added the actual trait code and explanation.  For anyone interested, the final Lift related code is [here](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/5ebe68f806beab0e)

Answer (score 9):

You can compose partial functions using the `orElse` method:

```
val f1: PartialFunction[Any, String] = {
  case 22 => "hallo"
}
val f2: PartialFunction[Any, String] = {
  case "rara" => "welt"
}

val f = f1 orElse f2 // f falls back to f2 if undefined in f1
f(22)
f("rara")
```